# PHP Присвоение переменной функции возвращает null

Tags: php, функции

Существует функция get_userID в файле functions.php , которая дастаёт из БД ID зарегестрированного пользователя. Вот она:

```
`function get_userID($arrUser) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username =  '{$arrUser}' ";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(!$res) return false;
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($res, 1);
        foreach($data AS $row) {
            echo $row['id'];
        }
    return;
}`
```

Вызывается она в файле profile.php и в её аргумент ($arrUser) попадают данные из сессии. При её вызове, она возвращает корректное значение, но если присвоить её какой-либо переменной, то возвращается NULL. Почему так происходит и где здесь искать ошибку?

```
`$userID = get_userID($user); 
echo '<br>';
var_dump($userID);`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так у вас написано что функция возвращает `NULL`, она его и возвращает. Вот же, в этой строке `return;`

Comment: `но если присвоить её какой-либо переменной` - то вместо echo напиши return

Comment: Я думаю что проблема кроется в переменной. Которая, судя по названию, является массивом. То есть автора вопроса волнует не то что выводится нулл, а то что функция ничего не выводит. А var_dump тут просто для проверки воткнут. Всё очень логично.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в функции get_userID() вместо return написать так:

```
return $data;
```

Comment: скорее на $data, а конкатекацию $row['id']

Comment: не return $data; а return mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!